# Xcode4, I've created a new scheme for adhoc, unlinked a library, but the build seems the same size?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I'm trying to automatically exclude a library from my release build, but have it present in my adhoc build.

I've found the file build file under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

I've deleted them, between builds, to make sure they were getting created as the modified date was the same. However, the build is the same size...

Remove from the libaray target. 
Make `AdHoc` build configuration by copying the `Release` build configuration. 
Add `-lTestFlight` in the `other linker flags` section of `AdHoc` build configuration.

Taken from http://d.hatena.ne.jp/basuke+en/20111122/1321924385

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily manage this by looking at your Build Target in XCode.

Select the one which you do not want to contain the library then click Build Phases and under the sections

Link Binary With Libraries 
Copy Bundle Resources

You should be able to remove the unwanted library for that particular build.